# Can a macro generate additional data?

Tags: macros, rust

```
foo!(x, y, z);
// expands to
fn xx(self) -> T {..}
fn xy(self) -> T {..}
...
fn xxx(self) -> T {..}
fn xxy(self) -> T {..}
fn xyz(self) -> T {..}
fn xzx(self) -> T {..}
//and so on
...
```

Is it possible for macros to generate additional data? I would like to implement vector swizzling. There are many combinations for a Vector4. 4 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4 = 291 combinations

I haven't done anything with macros besides simple substitution, so I am wondering if something like that could be expressed or do I need compiler plugins for that?

Comment: "additional data" is a very generic concept. Are you really asking if a macro can make an arbitrary number of functions based on the macro input?

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes I basically want to generate permutations of the macro input.

Comment: Then the answer is [basically no](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27415011/155423). (Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24905160/155423)). (Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23061702/155423)).

Comment: If you agree that this is a duplicate, feel free to mark it as whichever one was most useful. If you don't, [edit] your question to explain the differences.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I note that none of the duplicates mentions the use of a build script (which, in Rust, is quite more handy than in other languages due to being integrated to the build system). It could potentially be a reasonable alternative... depending on the specifics of the problem.

Comment: @MatthieuM. a good point! The downside is that you are going to have to treat all the Rust code as plain text. I think you can feel free to add that answer here or on any of the others.

Comment: @Shepmaster: The previous questions you linked present examples that are more "in situ" in the middle of existing code so I think I'll answer this one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Rust supports 3 methods of code generation:

- macros declared with `macro!`
- procedural macros relying on plugins (unstable)
- `build.rs`

The latter is a built-in [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) specifically supporting code generation/3rd-party libraries build (such as C libraries).

In your case, you are specifically interesting in the [Code Generation](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#case-study-code-generation) part, which is simple enough (quoting the docs):

> ```
> // build.rs
>
> use std::env;
> use std::fs::File;
> use std::io::Write;
> use std::path::Path;
>
> fn main() {
>     let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
>     let dest_path = Path::new(&out_dir).join("hello.rs");
>     let mut f = File::create(&dest_path).unwrap();
>
>     f.write_all(b"
>         pub fn message() -> &'static str {
>             \"Hello, World!\"
>         }
>     ").unwrap();
> }
> ```

Given this, you can automatically generate any `.rs` file before the build starts without encountering the macro hygiene issue or having to rely on a nightly compiler.