# How can I use a macro value as a part of a function name in stable Rust?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to write a macro like this:

```
macro_rules! impl_numeric_cast_methods {
    ($($ty:ty)*) => {
        $(
            fn from_$ty(v: $ty) -> Self {
                v as Self
            }
        )*
    }
}
```

The `from_$ty` bit doesn't work due to macro hygiene. I found that if `$ty` was an `ident` then I could (on unstable) possibly use [`concat_idents!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat_idents.html) except that that [apparently doesn't work either](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12249).

There's [a blog post about this issue](http://www.ncameron.org/blog/untitledconcat_idents-and-macros-in-ident-position/) and future plans to fix it, but my question is: how can I do this at all in today's Rust stable (1.15)? Is there a workaround?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/27415011/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/24905160/155423, many others.

Answer (score 1):

As a reasonable workaround, you can add the function names as extra parameters. It's not elegant but it works:

```
macro_rules! impl_numeric_cast_methods {
    ($($ty:ty, $from_ty:ident),*) => {
        $(
            fn $from_ty(v: $ty) -> Self {
                v as Self
            }
        )*
    }
}
```

Then call like:

```
impl_numeric_cast_methods(i8, from_i8, u8, from_u8);
```

A second macro could make the invocation shorter, but that would overcomplicate things in my case.

Comment: I'd suggest you remove this answer from this question and move it to the duplicate.

Comment: This is not "reasonable" and at least is prone to be subjective (what is reasonable and what isn't). This isn't a solution since it introduces far more repetitions and unnecessary arguments and doesn't actually solve the author's problem. There is, unfortunately, no solution to this in the vanilla Rust as of today. The "concat_idents!" macro is still nightly-only.